# How to deselect an option that comes from Array if another one is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have a component that will render my cards called CardListing as bellow;

```
return getWalletPayment.map(payment => (
  <CardListing
    key={payment._id}
    card={payment.card}
    cardNo={payment.cardNo}
    onChanged={selected => {
      this.setState({ selectedCard: selected });
    }}
  />
));
```

For now it will render two cards. If I select one everything is fine but if I select the second one the first one will stay selected until I tap on it again to deselect it.

Here is the implementation code

```
export default class CardListing extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: false,
      scaleCheckmarkValue: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
    this.scaleCheckmark = this.scaleCheckmark.bind(this);
    this.selectPaymentOption = this.selectPaymentOption.bind(this);
  }

  scaleCheckmark(value) {
    Animated.timing(this.state.scaleCheckmarkValue, {
      toValue: value,
      duration: 400,
      easing: Easing.easeOutBack
    }).start();
  }

  selectPaymentOption() {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      selected: !this.state.selected
    });
    this.props.onChanged(selected);
  }

  render() {
    const { selected, scaleCheckmarkValue } = this.state;
    const { card, cardNo } = this.props;
    const number = cardNo.substring(15);
    let logo;
    if (card == "visa") {
      logo = require("../../../assets/images/visa.png");
    }
    if (card == "master-card") {
      logo = require("../../../assets/images/mastercard.png");
    }
    if (card == "amex") {
      logo = require("../../../assets/images/amex.png");
    }
    if (card == "jcb") {
      logo = require("../../../assets/images/jcb.png");
    }
    if (card == "discover") {
      logo = require("../../../assets/images/discover.png");
    }
    const iconScale = this.state.scaleCheckmarkValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
      outputRange: [0.01, 1.6, 1]
    });

    const scaleValue = selected ? 1 : 0;
    this.scaleCheckmark(scaleValue);

    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.selectPaymentOption(this, cardNo)}
          style={styles.paymentOptionItem}
        >
          <View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-between"
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Image
                  source={logo}
                  style={{
                    width: 40,
                    height: 30,
                    marginTop: 3
                  }}
                />
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: "column"
                  }}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.paymentOptionTitle}>
                    {card.toUpperCase()}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.paymentOptionTitle}>Ending {number}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
              <Animated.View
                style={[
                  { transform: [{ scale: iconScale }] },
                  styles.iconWrapper
                ]}
              >
                <Icon name="check" color={colors.black} size={20} />
              </Animated.View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.divider} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: please include the implementation for `<CardListing/>`in your question

Comment: @DacreDenny have a look now as I have added the full implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider externalising the 'selected' state from the `<CardListing/>` component, so that the parent component tracks which credit card is currently selected (rather than each `<CardListing/>` tracking internal state to determine if it is selected).

First lift the `selected` outside of `<CardListing/>`, to the parent component. This will involve changes to your parent components map/render function, as shown:

```
/* 
Add this selectedCardId state to parent wallet component and
pass via selectedId. Also pass cardId prop so CardListing can
determine if it is the selected card
*/
return getWalletPayment.map(payment => (
  <CardListing
    key={payment._id}
    card={payment.card}
    cardNo={payment.cardNo}

    cardId={payment._id}
    selectedId={ this.state.selectedCard } 

    onChanged={selectedId => {
      this.setState({ selectedCard: selectedId});
    }}
  />
));
```

Next, revise the implementation of `<CardListing/>` so that `selected` is retrieved from `this.props` rather than `this.state`, and so that the `cardId` of the selected card is passed back via the `onChanged()` callback like so:

```
selectPaymentOption() {
  /*
  Pass the id of the card to be selected to callback
  */
  this.props.onChanged( this.props.cardId);
}

render() {
  /*
  Determine if this card should be rendered a the selected 
  card
  */
  const selected = this.selectedId === this.cardId;

  /* 
  Remaining render method remains unchanged
  */
}
```

Hope this helps!